# unittest's assert.equal returning not failing when it should

Tags: python

The function get_full_name capitalizes the first and last name and returns the full_name as below:

```
full_name = first + ' ' + last
full_name = full_name.title()
```

The following piece of code should fail but is passing. I'm using unittest.

```
formatted_name = get_full_name('janis', 'joplin')
self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'anis Joplin')
```

The unittest output is as below:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
```

Why is this test passing when it should fail?

The full code is posted below:

Here's the complete code for your review:

```
import unittest
def get_full_name(first, last):
    full_name = first + ' ' + last
    full_name = full_name.title()
    return full_name

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        formatted_name = get_full_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'anis Joplin',)
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The test isn't passing: `Ran 0 tests in ...` it didn't run your test case.  Can you post your full test script as well as how you're invoking it?

Comment: @thalesian1 Edit your post. Don't comment!

Comment: Please Edit your post with the command you are using to run unit test cases. Seems like your test cases is not getting called. see: `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`. Also, what is name of the file where `NamesTestCase` is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an indentation error.  Your `unittest.main()` call is within your class, and it should be at global level -- or, maybe better, within a main guard, like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Because statements within class bodies are still executed, the unittest runner is still called, but at the time it's called there are no defined subclasses of unittest.TestCase for it to find, which explains your  `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s` output.

Note that if you add a separate test class before your NamesTestCases, you'll see that those tests run even with `unittest.main()` being called at the wrong place, confirming the above.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this mistake. I've corrected it and my code now fails when it's supposed to.